# How to reference a URL object inside a function from ViewController.swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, wkwebview

I am trying to pass a web page to another WebView from ViewController.swift. The URL is initiated by another class.

So far I was able to create the webView, create the segue, and load a dummy web page inside that controller upon tapping on the button from ViewController.swift. When I tap the button, the correct web address gets printed on the console with `print(wikiURL)` call.

I tried to call the variable by first declaring a global variable inside ViewController, then modifying it inside the function, then trying to reach from the webView controller, by setting up variables.

This is the function I am calling the segue from:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WikiViewController") as? WikiViewController {
        guard let capital = view.annotation as? Capital else { return }
        let wikiURL = capital.url
        print(wikiURL)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

And this is my webView controller:

```
class WikiViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = webView.title
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
```

}

I should be able to replace `URL(string: "")!)` with `wikiURL`, then load it inside the webView.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: what is type `Capital?` - `var url: Capital?`

Comment: It is a code I forgot while trying to reference the url directly from the object class. I was trying to replace the url code with `URLRequest(url: url)`, `url` being the url property from the object class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WikiViewController`, instead of creating `url` of type `Capital?`, it must be of type `URL?`, i.e.

```
var url: URL?
```

Use this `url` to create the `URLRequest` for `WKWebView`.

```
class WikiViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var url: URL?

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = webView.title
        if let url = self.url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

When creating `instance` of `WikiViewController` in `mapView(_:,annotationView:, calloutAccessoryControlTapped:)` method, set the property `vc.url` as `wikiURL`.

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WikiViewController") as? WikiViewController {
    guard let capital = view.annotation as? Capital else { return }
    let wikiURL = capital.url
    print(wikiURL)
    vc.url = wikiURL //here......
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

**Note:** I've assumed that `wikiURL` is of type `URL?`. In case it is `String`, create a `URL` instance using that `String` and then set it as `vc.url`.